# SharePoint: Install and enable a feature, get access denied error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a SharePoint Timer from an Empty SharePoint project in VS2010. I have a class that inherits from SPJobDefinition.

I have the constructors, Execute method, et cetera. I also have a Feature which has a FeatureActivated and FeatureDeactivating event.

I am in Visual Studio as an administrator and I am farm admin on the server.

I am encountering 2 issues:

```
1. In Visual Studio I right click on the project and click 'Deploy' and I get 
an error.

Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool':
<nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.

2. The tutorials I have been following mention that in the Feature folder 
there will be a feature.xml however my features folder does not have that file,
am I missing something?
```

Edit:

On a tutorial it says to copy files to %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\

It also says each feature has its own subdirectory. At the root of this folder, a Feature.xml

I build the solution, go into the project folder then Features and there is no feature.xml

When I open the feature there is nothing in the "Items in this solution" box, is that right?

The machine with VS is the same machine with SP.

Comment: Have you tried deploying the .wsp directly with powershell? The problem is most likely, that the user on the machine running VS has no t sufficient rights on your SP machine, unless both are running on the same machine, which would be weird

Answer (score -1):

Try running Visual Studio as an administrator.  You also need to make sure your account has permissions (dbowner) I think on the content database of the web application that you are deploying to.

Comment: I am in Visual Studio as an administrator and I am farm admin on the server.